# Bamboo CI build of Visual Studio solution with build order dependencies

Tags: asp.net, .net, build, continuous-integration, bamboo

Seasoned developer setting up Bamboo Continuous Integration for the first time.
We have a single solution with multiple projects inside said solution. Lets say Main, Services, and Tests. Tests has a reference to the Main.dll and thus a build order dependency. I have Bamboo configured to run against the solution, but I can see that it's executing the build of Tests BEFORE Main.dll has been created. Which is causing it to fail because Main.dll does not exist.

So two questions:

1. How do I dictate to Bamboo that Main must be built before starting the build of Tests?
2. Is there a way to do a Bamboo build agains just 'Main' in order to confirm that it builds successfully? (My thought here is that perhaps 'Main' is failing to build/load and therefore being skipped over thus hitting Test which recoginizes Main.dll is missing)

**Bamboo Error**: *CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\bamboo....\PROGRAM\bin\Main.dll' could not be found*

Also: As I alluded to. On Visual Studio I see

```
1>----Build started: Project: Main Configuration: Debug Any CPU
2>----Build started: Project: Services Configuration: Debug Any CPU
2> Services -> C:\Path\Program\Main\bin\Services.dll
1> Main -> C:\Path\Program\Main\bin\Main.dll
3>----Build started: Project: Test Configuration: Debug Any CPU
3>Tests -> C:\Path\Program\Tests\bin\Test.dll
```

While Bamboo shows

```
1>----Build started: Project: Services Configuration: Debug Any CPU
1> Services -> C:\Path\Program\Main\bin\Services.dll
2>----Build started: Project: Test Configuration: Debug Any CPU
2> CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\bamboo\...\Project\Main\bin\Main.dll' could not be found
```

Comment: Still looking for a solution. Working with our IT guy I have a little more information. 

So for starters the issue appears to be surrounding the update of **.vs/config/applicationhost.**
If we log in as the Bamboo service account and open the Solution file (using Visual Studios), it updates the **.vs/config/applicationhost.** file (automatically) and everything is happy. However, when we do a clean build with Bamboo it fails to update the **.vs/config/applicationhost.** which results in the project not loading properly.

I am not sure how to debug the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

So we finally though trial and error resolved the issue.
Our IT admin had given the Bamboo-agent (user) full access to the directory identified, but other users simply had Read access. We ultimately had to grant all users (Public) full right access to the directory. So apparently the process uses an account other than Bamboo-agent during the task that requires permissions to update teh applicationhost file.